# Iterating over map to create key vault secrets throws error if secret doesn't exist

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a map of key vault secrets that I would want to use in an application.  Some of these already exist in Azure Key Vault:

```
variable "keyvault_secrets" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    service_bus = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus",
    mongo_connection = "MongoConnection",
    sendgrid_api_key = "SendgridApiKey",
    twilio_auth_token = "TwilioAccountAuthToken",
    twilio_sid = "TwilioAccountSid",
    twilio_message_service_sid = "TwilioMessageServiceSid",
    resdis_session_connection = "RedisSessionConnection"
  }
}
```

I then have the following blocks to create the key vault and secrets:

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "these" {
  for_each = var.keyvault_secrets
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.default.id
  name = each.value
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "api" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.default.id
  object_id = azurerm_app_service.api[0].identity[0].principal_id
  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  depends_on = [azurerm_app_service.api]
  key_permissions = []
  secret_permissions = [
    "Get"
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "default" {
  location = var.azure_location
  name = "kv-quiztime-${terraform.workspace}-001"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.default[0].name
  sku_name = module.vars.env["keyvault_plan_sku"]["name"]
  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  tags = local.common_tags
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "these" {
  for_each = var.keyvault_secrets
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.default.id
  name = each.value
  value = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.these[each.key] ? data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.these[each.key].value : "not set"
  content_type = "Connection String"
}
```

However, when I run `terraform plan` I get the following error:

> Error: KeyVault Secret "RedisSessionConnection" (KeyVault URI "https://kv-[hidden]-dev-001.vault.azure.net/") does not exist
> │
> │   with data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.these["resdis_session_connection"],
> │   on keyvaults.tf line 2, in data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "these":
> │    2: data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "these" {

Because it doesn't exist, I would expect it to be created.  What am I doing wrong? Or do I have incorrect expectations?

Comment: You are getting an error from the data source. Data sources aren't meant to be used for creating resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "does not exist" is from `data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.these`. Data sources **must exist**, otherwise you get that error. You can't query a data of a resource that does not exist. TF does not support such functionality nor it has no way to check for the existence beforehand.

You would have to design your own [custom data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) to implement working with resources that may or may not exist.

Comment: "Data sources must exist" Unfortunately with AWS provider 4.0 released yesterday, there are now data sources that can return empty lists for non-existing data sources. This will cause issues for old and new questions for sure.

Comment: This makes sense but seems like a catch-22 - is it best practice to just manually add secrets to the key vault then, and just import them into state?

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Its best to add them outside of TF - either manually, or through local-exect or some CI/CD pipeline. The reason is that all secrets end up in plain text in state file if created using TF.